# Android Studio: App crashes on some phones

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

I'm new at android development and really confused by this problem.
I'm making a simple app which has 3 TextViews: text, text2 and text3.

- **text** shows the latitude of user
- **text2** shows the longitude of the user and
- **text3** shows distance between user and the place called "Azadi Square".

The app runs properly on *`Samsung Galaxy S4`* and *`Samsung Galaxy Tab S`*, but in *`Huawei Y511`* and one of *`Sony Xperias`* (I do not know the exact name.), the app doesn't Open and says *`The App has unfortunately stopped`*

**Here is my Java code:**

```
public class Map extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private TextView text,text2,text3;
private String provider;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private double latitude,longitude;
private Location azadiSquare;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);

    azadiSquare = new Location(provider);
    azadiSquare.setLatitude(35.6996540);
    azadiSquare.setLongitude(51.3379906);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    text.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
    text2.setText(location.getLongitude()+"");
    text3.setText(distanceBetweenMeter(azadiSquare,location)+"");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,400,1,this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    text.setText(latitude+"");
    text2.setText(longitude+"");

    text3.setText(distanceBetweenMeter(azadiSquare,location)+"");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Enabled new provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Disabled provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2) {
    double R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    double dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    double dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
    double a =
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ;
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180);
}

private int distanceBetweenMeter(Location location1, Location location2){
    double distanceKM = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(location1.getLatitude(),location1.getLongitude(),
            location2.getLatitude(),location2.getLongitude());
    int distanceMeter = (int)(distanceKM*1000);
    return distanceMeter;
}
}
```

**Note: I just deleted the imports!**

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Map" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Notes:** I turned On the Location of the phone before opening the app, so it is not the problem. The other thing I want to say is that all the calculations are okay and they are working fine.

Comment: When it give the message, "unfortunately has stopped" on the screen, there must be some log there. Run the app on Huawei y511 or Sony Xperia in debug mode and get the log. Edit your original question and paste the error.

Comment: can you share your app's build.gradle?

Answer (score 3):

On `Android 6.0 (API level 23`) and higher you need to request permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` at run time. See, [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). That may be the case.

Comment: thanks for answering so fast.  but all of phones i mentioned have android 4 or 5...

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to logcat the issue and backtrace it so you could see where it's going bad or at least have one clue. If the answer from user35603 didn't worked then try this and post the logcat part regarding to your issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer. how can i logcat on phone? i think i should say that i build apk and install it on phone. so i do not know how to logcat...

Comment: The best way to show you it on stackoverflow is to check out these useful links:

You need to install the ADB drivers if you haven't done it yet but I assume you already have them because you have android studio:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118

Then go to the directory or if a path has been set with the CMD and then follow the link on google to use ADB
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: If you don't understand it after my first comment, this tutorial could clear you up a bit as stackoverflow doesn't allow too long and detailed stories
:http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2141817

Comment: actually i know how to use adb but the problem is that adb doesn`t have Location. does it make any problems?

Comment: It doesn't make any problems as adb is just used as an bridge between your phone and your pc. You will see where the issue related to perhaps location will occur if u succeed in logcatting. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is solved! This part of the code was making trouble:

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

text.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
text2.setText(location.getLongitude()+"");
```

I guess it takes a little bit of time for *`location`* to get the current location. Actually, when app wants to run the line below, location is still null and app crashes:

```
text1.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
```

I solved the crash with something like this:

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

while(location==null){}

text.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
text2.setText(location.getLongitude() + "");
text3.setText(distanceBetweenMeter(azadiSquare,location)+"");
```

Crash is solved, but the app freezes with white screen. I don't know exactly, but I guess it is trapped on *`while`* loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

pb=findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
Example ex=new Example();//The subclass object is created here
boolean stop=false;//a boolean variable to start or stop the thread to get location. 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (location== null) {
        showSettingDialog();//this will show your custom way of displaying 
                              //the location setting intent
        new Thread(ex).start();//here the fetching location gets started
    }
    else{
       //here write code after your location is fetched
       //here to got some other base activity or stay in this
        finish();//if you wan to stay in this activity then omit this line.
    }
}

public class Example implements Runnable{ //This is a sub class in your main activity.

    @Override
    public void run() {//overriding run medthod
            try {

                while(location==null) { //this part keeps on running whithout 
                                         //ui freeze
                     if (stop) {
                        return;
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    getLastLocation();//this function will fetch location.
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    if (location != null) {
                        //do your code here
                        stop = true;
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }


             catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of simply posting code fragments. Other users should be able to learn from your answer.

Comment: hey david! the problem here is when your location is not turned on or your gps is not feteching location because of low gps signal. to avoid this problem just make your app show some progress bar in ui thread and in background thread make that while state statement to fetch location so that the ui wont look freezed as well as you will get location in background thread.

Comment: Good, but please try to update your answer in an explaing way. Thanks!